# Geofence example with parcelables as Extras

Tags: android, android-geofence

I'm following the example from https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html and implementing an app with geofences.

I have modified the getGeofencePendingIntent() method as follows:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.class);
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putInt(GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.NTH_EXTRA_FIELD,currentClue);
    extras.putLong(GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.GAME_ID_EXTRA_FIELD,gameId);
    //extras.putParcelableArrayList(GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.ROUTES_EXTRA_FIELD,MainActivity.routes);
    //extras.putParcelable(GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.USER_EXTRA_FIELD, MainActivity.user);
    intent.putExtras(extras);
    return PendingIntent.getService(getActivity(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

As you can see the difference with the example is that I use extras to pass some info, because I need it to start the activity from the notification.

The problem is that if I uncomment those two lines with parcelable extras, in the onHandleIntent() method in GeofenceTransitionsIntentService class I receive a -1 as geofenceTransition, and if I let those lines commented, it works fine and receive Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER value. What is happening here? I have to say that the extras from Intent are correctly received.

```
    GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
    if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
        String errorMessage = GeofenceErrorMessages.getErrorString(this,
                geofencingEvent.getErrorCode());
        Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
        return;
    }

    // Get the transition type.
    int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();
```

Thank you